# What is the best way to publish an Electron Application in order to avoid Windows Defender and Smart Screen?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-forge

I am trying to publish an Electron App on arc=x64 and platform=win32 built with Electron-Forge in Squirrel.Windows format, but Windows shows a lot of errors, like: ,, Microsoft Defender Smart Screen prevented an unrecognized app from starting ", windows defender waiting for accept.

Is there a way to avoid those errors without having to buy a certificate which costs 300-400$?

And the app should be distributed just with app.exe or should i zip all 3 files together: .nupkg, .exe and RELEASES? Thank you!

Should i use WiX MSI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SmartScreen uses reputation algorithmn. It block executables with bad reputation.
Young and new applications have zero reputation and blocked by default.

It takes several hundred installs to convince smartscreen that it is legitimate. So, just repeatedly install it manually on various test/dev machines or convince your users to ignore/passthrough smartscreen warning.

We had this problem. We ended buying EV certification (~1K$, but can find cheaper)